# Office 365 Mail API execute Search in .NET

Tags: c#, search, outlook, odata, office365

I am working on an C# desktop application that can do some operations in Office365 Mail.
I am using the client libraries in C# to create queries to retrieve emails.
But I am stuck at the search function which I want to create in my application.

According to the [Resource reference of the Mail API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#UseODataqueryparametersSearchrequests) I can use the $search parameter to execute a search against the inbox for example.
But I can’t find any function in the client library to accomplish this?
So I tried to use the String.Contains function in the where-clause but this creates a query with a $filter:

```
var query = (from i in client.Users[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SharedMailbox"]].Folders["Inbox"].Messages
            where(i.From.EmailAddress.Address.Contains(searchString))
            select new MessageCompact()
            {
            Id = i.Id,
            ParentFolderId = i.ParentFolderId,
            DateTimeReceivedOffset = i.DateTimeReceived,
            Sender = i.Sender.EmailAddress.Address,
            Subject = i.Subject,
            BodyPreview = i.BodyPreview,
            Categorieen = i.Categories
        });

var messageResults = await foundedMessages.ExecuteAsync();
```

When executing I get the exception:

> Exception:Thrown: "{"error":{"code":"ErrorInvalidUrlQueryFilter","message":"'contains' and 'startswith' are not supported for filtering.  Use Search instead."}}" (Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceClientException)
>   A Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceClientException was thrown: "{"error":{"code":"ErrorInvalidUrlQueryFilter","message":"'contains' and 'startswith' are not supported for filtering.  Use Search instead."}}"

When I manually add the search option, using this code, I get the exception

```
DataServiceQuery<Message> foundedMessages = client.Users[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SharedMailbox"]].Folders["Inbox"].Messages.Context
                                        .CreateQuery<Message>("Users('xyz@abc.com')/Folders('Inbox')/Messages")
                                        .AddQueryOption("$search", searchString);
```

> Exception:Thrown: "Can't add query option '$search' because it begins with reserved character '$'." (System.NotSupportedException)
>   A System.NotSupportedException was thrown: "Can't add query option '$search' because it begins with reserved character '$'."

How can I accomplish a search using the client library in .NET?

Marcel

Comment: This might be the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923539/odata-search-with-office-365-mail-api-net-client