# OData Search with Office 365 Mail API .NET Client

Tags: c#, odata, office365, office365api, office365-restapi

I need to perform an OData query $search = "subject:pizza" using the OutLook 365 API but using the Outlookservicesclient (found the in the outlook 365 sdk, this nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices-V2.0/)

See this [OutLookAPI OData query Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#UseODataqueryparametersSearchrequests)

This works correctly using an HttpClient but with the .NET client library, its seemingly not possible to add any non-standard query parameters.

Ie: `var messages = await client.Users['mail@me.com'].Messages
                                    .Where(m => m.IsRead == false)
                                    .Take(50)
                                    .ExecuteAsync();`

Produces the following RequestURI `https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/Users('mail%40me.com')/Messages?$filter=IsRead eq false&$top=50` And executes correctly.

Whereas if try the following, `var query = client.Users['Mail@me.com'].Messages
                    .Context.CreateQuery<Message>("Users('Mail@me.com')/Messages")
                    .AddQueryOption("$search", "subject:pizza");`

Either returns `Exception:Thrown: "Can't add query option '$search' because it begins with reserved character '$'." (System.NotSupportedException) A System.NotSupportedException was thrown: "Can't add query option '$search' because it begins with reserved character '$'."`

or im getting authentication errors if I omit the AddQueryOption line.

All I need to do as append `$search=subject:pizza` the RequestURI! This seems impossible without actually using a rest client as the Outlook Client seems limited to built in Linq methods.

Added the fact there is no reference documentation for the client library, ive hit a dead end. Does anyone know if its possible to include $search via the outlookservicesclient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked with the OData.NET folks, and they've opened an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues/399) to track the error adding `$search` with `AddQueryOption`. In the meantime, they suggested you could try something like this to make it work:

```
var query = context.CreateQuery("Users('Mail@me.com')/Messages");
var searchUri = new Uri(query.RequestUri.OriginalString + "?$search=%22subject%3Apizza%22");
var messages =  context.Execute<Message>(searchUri, "Get");
```

Comment: Thanks @Jason-Johnston, but unfortunately im getting a 401 erro when trying it this way. Bearing in mind I am using "client credential grant" flow to get my access token (outlined here [link](https://github.com/mattleib/o365api-as-apponly-webapp)

Comment: That sounds like a separate problem. Does it generate the properly formatted request?

Comment: Ah apologies, after looking at the Fiddler results, the Authorization header was empty, I had to manually  insert using  `e.RequestMessage.SetHeader("Authorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", appstate.AccessToken));` on the SendingRequest2EventArgs